# Change the character that is appear with Merge Field in Microsoft Word

Tags: microsoft-word

I'm trying to add a MergeField in Microsoft Word.

When I add the field (QuickPart->Field->MergeFeild) it adds the field and it appears like this: `«GAP WAIVER»`, but I need it appear like this: `**GAP WAIVER**`.

How I can change `«` to `**`?

solution:
I opened the document in notepad and did the change.

Comment: Beware, because it's not a permanent change. Although you can change them manually (even in Word itself), a number of things will make them revert - e.g. if a user uses the UI to move from one merge record to another, the chevrons will reappear. Even Save/Close/re-open may lose the asterisks.

Answer (score 0):

We believe it is not possible to change the symbol for Merge field from `« to **` . Word has some default symbols and attributes for specific operations. These symbol were used only for these oprations

For example you can find the same merge option in mail merge where we unable to change the symbol similar to your merge field in Microsoft word. Option to change the symbol is disabled when we customize the merge field. Below is the example of the same.

[image]

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can do a find and replace to substitute the default merge field arrows for stars instead. Since these symbols appear in the field result and not the field code you can name the fields whatever you want and it won't affect how the mail merge behaves.